# Can't get value from nested pair in Omniauth hash.

Tags: ruby, hash, omniauth

I'll try to keep this simple, my previous wording was maybe a bit too verbose:

Here is the example Omniauth hash: https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook

I can access and save some values from this but not others. The field is writable, so I know its just my syntax (beginner, sorry!)

```
{
  :provider => 'facebook',
  :uid => '1234567',
  :info => {
    :nickname => 'jbloggs',
    :email => 'joe@bloggs.com',
    :name => 'Joe Bloggs',
    :first_name => 'Joe',
    :last_name => 'Bloggs',
    :image => 'http://graph.facebook.com/1234567/picture?type=square',
    :urls => { :Facebook => 'http://www.facebook.com/jbloggs' },
    :location => 'Palo Alto, California',
    :verified => true
  },
  :credentials => {
    :token => 'ABCDEF...', # OAuth 2.0 access_token, which you may wish to store
    :expires_at => 1321747205, # when the access token expires (it always will)
    :expires => true # this will always be true
  },
  :extra => {
    :raw_info => {
      :id => '1234567',
      :name => 'Joe Bloggs',
      :first_name => 'Joe',
      :last_name => 'Bloggs',
      :link => 'http://www.facebook.com/jbloggs',
      :username => 'jbloggs',
      :location => { :id => '123456789', :name => 'Palo Alto, California' },
      :gender => 'male',
      :email => 'joe@bloggs.com',
      :timezone => -8,
      :locale => 'en_US',
      :verified => true,
      :updated_time => '2011-11-11T06:21:03+0000'
    }
  }
}
```

I can do this to get gender and save it.

```
location:auth.extra.raw_info["gender"]
```

Obviously though I dont want to save gender to location. I want to get "Palo Alto" and save it. But this doesn't work.

```
location.auth.extra.raw_info["location"]["name"]
```

What am I doing wrong? When I try it in console, I'm able to get the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
location.auth.extra.raw_info.location.name
```

or this

```
location.auth.extra.raw_info[:location][:name]
```

Comment: Hmmm....I tried both of those already but neither worked. And I just tried again. Still no.

Comment: Well, I think I found the problem - but confirming still.... the omniauth hash seems to no longer return the user's location.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, what you suggested was what I was trying...and it turns out we were right but FB had changed how that hash was set up so it wasn't working.  Lesson learned: subscribe FB's notifications next time :)